# Adding reference to C# Project

Tags: c#, reference, explorer

I'm having an issue adding a reference to my C# project. I need to add a dll called PhpNetCore. I have located this DLL with Windows Explorer in Assembly\GAC_MSIL\PhpNetCore. However, when I browse with the Visual Studio explorer to add a reference to the DLL it doesn't show up. They are simply not visible. What gives?

Using Windows Explorer, I copied the PhpNetCore folder to my desktop. I was then able to add a reference without any issues.

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Geoff

Comment: C# projects should **never** reference an assembly in the GAC.  That merely ensures they'll build correctly once.  The odds go down in a hurry after that, you don't put the GAC in source control and you surely won't remember what version you needed and how to get it a couple of months from now.  Reference assemblies must be stable copies.

Comment: @HansPassant Never? What about assemblies that are part of the [Framework Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Class_Library)?

Comment: *Especially* not framework assemblies.  Their reference assemblies come from c:\program files\reference assemblies today, c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework previously.

Answer (score 0):

That's "as designed" for Visual Studio. The GAC is for publishers to share assemblies with multiple applications. Publishers can share assemblies with developers in Common Files\Reference Assemblies.

The ideal method of adding a reference to your project is to use the NuGet package manager.

If neither of those are available, copying is okay, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that library but I found a way to use it installation free if this is of any help.

[Installation-Free Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2011/installation-free-phalanger-web)